# jQuery element reloader

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have looked around for an already existing script for this, but couldn't find one, so i decided to make my own.

The point of this is to make it easy to reload an element, whether its a form or a link.

To use the script, you add a class to the link/form called "js_container-reloader".
What the script does is it simply gets the content of the action url or href, creates a wrapper around the element you are reloading, takes the ajax response and puts it in to the wrapper, then removes the wrapper.

Its working as it should at the moment, but i wonder if there is a better way of doing this.

```
//Form element reloader
$(document).on("submit", ".js_container-reloader", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //Call the reloader function
    elementReloader(e.currentTarget);
});


//Link element reloader
$(document).on("click", ".js_container-reloader", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    //Call the reloader function
    elementReloader(e.currentTarget);
});


/*  Element reloader function
*   Takes an element and the type of request this is */
function elementReloader(element){

    //Set variables
    var element = $(element),
        requestUrl,
        requestType,
        data,
        reloadContainer;


    //Wrap the element in a reloader div and save the div to a variable
    element.wrap("<div class='dv_dis-i js_reload-container'></div>");
    reloadContainer = element.closest('.js_reload-container');


    //If the element is a form
    if(element.is("form")){

        //Save the forms action
        requestUrl = element.attr('action');

        //Save the request type
        requestType = element.attr('method');

        //Save the forms data
        data = element.serialize();


    //If the request should be done by GET
    }else{

        //Get the forms action
        requestUrl = element.attr('href');

        //Save the request type
        requestType = "GET";
    }


    //Run the ajax script
    $.ajax({
        type: requestType,
        url: requestUrl,
        data: data,
        success: function(result){

            //If the result returned false, reload the alert container
            if(!result){
                reloadAlertContainer();

            //If its not false then load the container with the result
            }else{

                //Add the result to the wrapper
                reloadContainer.html(result);

                //Remvoe the wrapper
                reloadContainer.find(".js_container-reloader").unwrap();
            }
        },
        error: function(xhr) {

            /*  Reload the alerts container
            *   An alert is saved to the session if there was an error
            *   with any script that was loaded.
            *   This function reloads the container which shows the session alert. */
            reloadAlertContainer();
        },
    });
}
```

I don't assume my code is expert level as i am not an expert, but the goal is to make it as easy and dynamic as possible for future implementations.
I tried looking in to combining the code, especially the first 2 functions for the event listeners, together in to one function, but couldn't find a way that seemed like a proper solution.

Just to clarify about the form posting - i do the form validation and checking in php, in the actual file that is being loaded, and not in JavaScript/jQuery. This script is just for reloading elements.

Comment: Personally I think you would be better switching on the element's type (FORM or A) rather than if a specific attribute. I would also get the method from the form's `method` aattribute. Also I notice that you pass in a `type` parameter but don't use it.

Comment: Thank you! I updated the code and added the forms actual method (didn't think about forms having a GET option!), and i use the type now, i forgot i was even sending that. And what do you mean exactly by switching on the elements type? At what point in the code are you referring to?

Comment: @MarcRohloff please add an answer instead of a comment. Refer to the section **When _shouldn't_ I comment?** on [Comment everywhere](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Too late, the code is changed now. Answer invalidation and all that. But you're absolutely right that the comment should've been posted as an answer. Just, not now. Too late.

Comment: @MarcRohloff I actually ended up changing the code even more in my script and switching the element types, there were issues with the way i was doing it, but now it seems to be much better and more dynamic. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry I was busier earlier. Here is a more complete review. Just a few things off the top of my head.

- Try and be consistent with your class naming. Instead of  `.js_container-reloader` and `js_reload-container` use a common prefix, i.e. `.js_reloader-trigger` (or even just `.js_reloader`) and `.js_reloader-container`
- You can use a single call to the `on` function like:

  $(document).on("submit", ".js_container-reloader", ...
- `var element = $(element),` is syntactically incorrect since `element` is already defined as a parameter. One options is just use `element = $(element);`  another pattern I often see is using a `$` prefix on variables to indicate jQuery objects, i.e. `var $element = $(element),`
- `requestUrl = element.attr('action');` would be better as`requestUrl = element.prop('action');` the latter will retrieve the default method for the form if no attribute is set.
- I personally think the use of `wrap and`unwrap` is an odd way to handle adding an element. I would remove the wrap and container code and just have something like the following on success:

  ```
  success: function(result){
     ....
     element.after(result);
     element.remove();
  ```
- I would add a `.js_reloader-loading` class to the element before starting the ajax query so that you can style it differently (fade it, add a spinner, etc).
- Lastly you probably want to implement some kind of logic to prevent multiple attempts at loading the form.

Comment: Great suggestions, thanks! i have a few questions about some of the points: "You can use a single call to the on function like" - im not sure exactly what you mean, do you mean that instead of having two listeners, one for click and one for submit, i can have just the submit listener?

Comment: And yes i agree about the wrapping and unwrapping, but if i use the `.after()` function, would there basically be a very shortly visible duplicate or the elements? For example, if i have a like button and i click it, wouldnt using `.after()` add the new button after it and then only remove the existing one, resulting in showing both buttons (even though it would just be momentary)?

Comment: "Lastly you probably want to implement some kind of logic to prevent multiple attempts at loading the form." - i completely forgot about this when i was writing this code, i agree, i have to think about how this should be done, maybe when clicking on it, the current element should lose all click functionality, that way you wont be able to click on it again and trigger the script again before it reloads, or do you know of a better way?

Comment: also, when you say to use `requestUrl = element.prop('action');` do you mean to switch `requestType = element.attr('method');` to: `requestUrl = element.prop('method');` ?

Comment: Yes, you can use that syntax  to listen to both events with a single listener function

Comment: There are a couple of ways of prevent multiple executions. (1) If you add a `loading` class you can check if that is present (2) you can have a flag variable that you set and clear. (3) Hiding the whole form and replacing it with a spinner. Regardless I suggest you provide visual feedback (for example greying out the submit button)

Comment: Yes, I meant to replace `attr` with `prop`. If you test you will find that the former does not return a value if no `method` attribute is provided.

Comment: Thanks for that, i changed things up a bit, i use the ´on.("submit click")´ now for both, and i put the actual function inside of this since i only saved it as an external function because i had two seperate event listers, so now its all in one code. I also went with adding a class to prevent double clicking, so when the script is triggered, a class js_clicked is added, and the script checks if the class is set, if so then return false, and when the ajax is complete i remove the class

Comment: Also, instead of using the .after and .remove, i used .replaceWith() which seems to be working

Comment: I would like to show the updated code but im not sure if i can do that here without breaking any rules.. But i have pretty much improved it so almost v2.0 i would say (if we would rate by versions)